# How can we find out how many records has been inserted in or not in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I want to know how can we find the **number of records** that has been inserted in SSIS?

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using? If 2012 do you have SSISDB setup?

Comment: You should state your question more precisely. Nobody knows what SSIS means in your context. SSIS stands for SQL Servier Integration Services. Explain the concept of your package.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways.   One is to use the Record Count transformation to populate a variable, and look at the value of that variable after the DataFlow Task completes.